# Is in Java method reference a part of the reflection API

Tags: java, reflection, method-reference

In Kotlin, the result of a method-reference is placed in the package kotlin.reflect. Is the method-reference in Java also part of the reflection-api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual type implementing the functional interface for method references is intentionally unspecified. All that matters, is, that it is provided by the current JRE.

Practically, in the case of HotSpot/OpenJDK, it is a runtime generated class that resides within the same package and class loading context as the class containing the method reference. It does not inherit from a special class and does not implement other interfaces besides the interfaces defined by its target type. So while this class has some special properties, i.e. it can not get looked up by name and it may get garbage collected regardless of the reachability of its defining class loader, but it’s not part of the Reflection API.

The properties of the instance created for a method reference are specified by [the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.3) as follows:

> The value of a method reference expression is a reference to an instance of a class with the following properties:
>
> - The class implements the targeted functional interface type and, if the target type is an intersection type, every other interface type mentioned in the intersection.
> - Where the method reference expression has type `U`, for each non-`static` member method `m` of `U`:
>
>   If the function type of `U` has a subsignature of the signature of `m`, then the class declares an *invocation method* that overrides `m`. The invocation method's body invokes the referenced method, creates a class instance, or creates an array, as described below. If the invocation method's result is not `void`, then the body returns the result of the method invocation or object creation, after any necessary assignment conversions (§5.2).
>
>   If the erasure of the type of a method being overridden differs in its signature from the erasure of the function type of `U`, then before the method invocation or object creation, an invocation method's body checks that each argument value is an instance of a subclass or subinterface of the erasure of the corresponding parameter type in the function type of `U`; if not, a `ClassCastException` is thrown.
> - The class overrides no other methods of the functional interface type or other interface types mentioned above, although it may override methods of the `Object` class.